# File Upload in WebView doesn't work

Tags: android

```
public class cloud extends Activity 
{
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cloud);
    setTitle("AmigoFriends");
        WebView myWebView01 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        String strURI = "http://amigofriends.mis.nsysu.edu.tw/e/mobile/";   
        myWebView01.loadUrl(strURI);              
        myWebView01.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});     
        WebSettings websettings = myWebView01.getSettings();             
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        websettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        websettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true); 
        WebSettings settings = myWebView01.getSettings(); 
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);      
         }


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    WebView myWebView01 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    {   
        boolean CloseYN;
            if(myWebView01.canGoBack())
            {
                CloseYN = false;
                myWebView01.goBack();
            }
            else
            {
                CloseYN = true;
            }
            event.startTracking();
            return CloseYN;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

    }
}

  protected class CustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient 
  {
      // For Android > 4.1
       public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
       {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
        }
       // Andorid 3.0 + 
       public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) 
       {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
        }
       //Android 3.0
       public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) 
       {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    }

class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient 
{
    // The undocumented magic method override
    // Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
    {

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        cloud.this.startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"),
                FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a description of your problem. What does "doesn't work" mean? What do you expect and what do you observe? Also, please fix your code formatting.

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time I post the question.
My code can't upload file when I click the button in the webview. And I want my code can upload files from my mobile phone but there is no happen when i click the button.